# Is it safe to use WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION to receive broadcast when Wifi connection is established successfully?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I know most people check [`ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) for receiving broadcast when connectivity is changed. However, in some cases, you may only want to get notified when wireless connection is establish successfully.

Personally, my case is that I need to post a login request when user has connected to certain wirless network. After some Googling, I got to [`WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION), but it is poorly ducumented thus its reliability  is doubted. So I need to confirm whether this intent is **always** fired after wireless configuration has **completed successfully**.

Anyway, here is the code I use in my `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class StateChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if (!networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return;
        }

        WifiInfo wifiInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO);
        if (!wifiInfo.getSSID().equals(THE_SSID_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR)) {
            return;
        }

        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

When testing with my Samsung S4 (I959) device, my broadcast receiver failed to receive the broadcast. Common approach using ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION seems more reliable across different manufacturers. so you may want to use it instead.

Below is my previous investigation on this broadcast.

---

Here is what I got from 4.4.4_r1 source.

From `WifiStateMachine` [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java), the first thing to see is the states of the state machine, which is [inside its constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java#784). Note that the latter is the parent state of the former.

```
addState(mDefaultState);
    addState(mInitialState, mDefaultState);
    addState(mSupplicantStartingState, mDefaultState);
    addState(mSupplicantStartedState, mDefaultState);
        addState(mDriverStartingState, mSupplicantStartedState);
        addState(mDriverStartedState, mSupplicantStartedState);
            addState(mScanModeState, mDriverStartedState);
            addState(mConnectModeState, mDriverStartedState);
                addState(mL2ConnectedState, mConnectModeState);
                    addState(mObtainingIpState, mL2ConnectedState);
                    addState(mVerifyingLinkState, mL2ConnectedState);
                    addState(mCaptivePortalCheckState, mL2ConnectedState);
                    addState(mConnectedState, mL2ConnectedState);
                addState(mDisconnectingState, mConnectModeState);
                addState(mDisconnectedState, mConnectModeState);
                addState(mWpsRunningState, mConnectModeState);
        addState(mWaitForP2pDisableState, mSupplicantStartedState);
        addState(mDriverStoppingState, mSupplicantStartedState);
        addState(mDriverStoppedState, mSupplicantStartedState);
    addState(mSupplicantStoppingState, mDefaultState);
    addState(mSoftApStartingState, mDefaultState);
    addState(mSoftApStartedState, mDefaultState);
        addState(mTetheringState, mSoftApStartedState);
        addState(mTetheredState, mSoftApStartedState);
        addState(mUntetheringState, mSoftApStartedState);
```

Thankfully the names are almost self-explanatory. You can easily notice the states we are interested in. To see what really happens, we can search the source for these states.

The first method we investigate would be [`sendNetworkStateChangeBroadcast`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java#WifiStateMachine.sendNetworkStateChangeBroadcast%28java.lang.String%29). Its invocation can be identified inside [`VerifyingLinkState`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java#3826) and [`CaptivePortalCheckState`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java#3869), and some others you may find out for yourself.

Inside `CaptivePortalCheckState`, when [processing `CMD_CAPTIVE_CHECK_COMPLETE`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java#3869), you can finally confirm that when the checking is finished and network is fully configured, we will receive the state change intent in our app with `CONNECTED` state in `NetworkInfo` extra along with a `WifiInfo`.

Last but not least, we look back into the history. Personally I'm interested in 4.x platforms, so I turned to the source of 4.0.1_r1. It is a bit surprising that this version seems to be more readable than the latter one. You can find that [`sendNetworkStateChangeBroadcast`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java#WifiStateMachine.sendNetworkStateChangeBroadcast%28java.lang.String%29) is fired inside [`handleSuccessfulIpConfiguration`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java#WifiStateMachine.handleSuccessfulIpConfiguration%28android.net.DhcpInfoInternal%29) (and other methods), which is fired in [`ConnectingState.processMessage()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java#2838) and [`ConnectedState.processMessage()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java#2907) when ip has been configured successfully.

So we finally arrive at the conclusion, using [`WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java#WifiManager.0NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION) to track successful wireless connection, is safe and appropriate.

If you have any other questions related to WifiManager broadcasts, you can also refer to the source code mentioned above and find it out for yourself :)

Comment: Finally, one that works. Thank you so much. Your use-case is exactly mine. May the Gods smile on your path!